# What do "IS" "IL" and "IEXT" refer to in the RDF Semantics specification?

Tags: rdf, definition, interpreted-language

These terms are used in the "Definition of a simple interpretation" table on http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-rdf-mt-20040210/#interp .  I am a little unclear on their meaning.

At this point I think they mean, Intermediate Language,

I am a little unclear on the meaning of these abbreviations.  I am guessing that they mean Intermediate Language, Intermediate System, and Intermediate Extension (or any of these, substituting "interpretation" for "intermediate").  This information isn't explicit in the documentation, and I don't have enough context to know conclusively what is being referred to.

**Edit** *I copied the section where it is used below:*

```
Definition of a simple interpretation.

A simple interpretation I of a vocabulary V is defined by:

1. A non-empty set IR of resources, called the domain or universe of I.

2. A set IP, called the set of properties of I.

3. A mapping IEXT from IP into the powerset of IR x IR i.e. the set 
   of sets of pairs <x,y> with x and y in IR .

4. A mapping IS from URI references in V into (IR union IP)

5. A mapping IL from typed literals in V into IR.

6. A distinguished subset LV of IR, called the set of literal values, 
   which contains all the plain literals in V
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a little inscrutable, unless you're used to formal logic.

An *interpretation* is a particular understanding of a set of statements in some artificial language (in this case RDF). It sounds grand, but it's typically so obvious you don't even think about it. For example `:a :p :b .` might have an interpretation '`:a` is Anne, `:b` is Bob, and `:p` is lives-next-to'. Armed with that mapping between terms and things you can interpret `:a :p :b`. Many other interpretations are possible.

RDF simple interpretations are just such a mapping (actually, a set of mappings). They each have terse labels.

1. `IR` (Interpretation Resources), a set of all the things we can talk about (Anne, Bob, clouds etc.).
2. `IP` (Interpretation Property), a set of all the properties we can talk about (love, lives-next-door-to etc).
3. `IEXT` (Interpretation Extension). Explains what the *extension* of a property is. Informally the extension of a property `P` is all the pairs of things for which the property hold. So even if you don't understand 'blarg' you can work out whether `:a :blarg :b` by just looking for `<:a, :b>` in the extension of `:blarg`. The definition given is a formalised version of this: you map properties into the set of all pairs of resources.
4. `IS` (Interpretation Subjects). Assigns URIs to all things which might appear in the subject position (resources and properties). (`V` is the vocabulary -- the terms -- of the language).
5. `IL` (Interpretation Literal).  Maps typed literal terms to things.

Answer (score 4):

The definitions are given in the quoted text you pasted. e.g. "5. A mapping IL from typed literals in V into IR." defines IL.

IL is defined as a mathematical map function. The key of the map (from): literals in V. The value of the map (to): IR

and so on for IS and IEXT

Comment: +1, Thank you, your answer was helpful but the selected one was more complete.